# Correct morphological parse of a word "indecipherable"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, morphology, derivational-morphology

What will be the correct morphological parse of word

```
 indecipherable in-prefix>decipher-stem>able-suffix
    or 


     indecipherable in-prefix>de- prefix >cipher-stem>able-suffix
```

What will be the correct bracketing for above ?

Comment: The logical decomposition is _un-_ `Not` (_-able_ `Possible` (_de-_ `Reverse` (_cipher_))). In other words, something that is indecipherable is something that is not possible to decipher. This is unambiguous, unlike the morphological parse of _unlockable_, which can either mean 'not able to be locked' or 'able to be unlocked'.

Comment: @JohnLawler. It c an be segmented further.

Comment: @ what will be the correct bracketing in that case

Comment: @JohnLawler.  What will be the bracketing ?

Comment: (in ((de cipher) able))

Comment: @HotLicks, what will be the "correct" stem?

Comment: What means "correct stem"?

Comment: @JohnLawler   A stem that native speaker would identify as stem easily and it can't be segmented further.

Comment: The "stem", in the sense that I'd use the term, is "cipher'.  To "cipher" something is (in this sense) to encode it.  To "decipher" is to decode it.

Answer (score 2):

The stem "decipher" is taken as the argument of the recursive function such that:

indecipherable: (in-prefix>decipher-stem>able-suffix)   *becomes*

indecipherable: ( **in**-prefix>**decipher**-stem (**de**-prefix>**cipher**-stem)>**able**-suffix)

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: The recursion is the fact that a secondary parse is being included in a primary or parent parse, so this actually means that both parse forms that you had given as options should be unified into a comprehensive morphological parse; "decipher" is also a component that can be decomposed into standard grammatical units. The recursive (unified) morphological parse should illustrate this idea.

Comment: could you please explain further ?

Comment: which is the "correct" stem

Comment: "cipher" is the absolute stem.

Comment: So, we can limit the segmentation to cipher ?

Comment: yes,  definitely